# Paypal smart buttons 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'

Tags: javascript, paypal

So I have been using paypal smart buttons for months in my localhost for testing and it worked fine but it suddenly stopped working. this is the error message
[image]

what's the cause of this?

Comment: How are you integrating the buttons? Are you [using the JavaScript SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/)? It might help to show your code.

Comment: Voting to close due to lack of details, but that message has nothing to do with your problem

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100 % sure but I think this error appears just if you use sandbox api credentilas.
Had the same error using sandbox api key and found nothing in the whole wide web to fix that error.
But if I use a live api key the error seems to be gone

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31503246)

Answer (score 0):

Try with another browser like Firefox and without additional settings, the connection error can sometimes be caused by cookies or extensions.

Comment: Seems like if you know what he's talking about (paypal subscriptions) you have enough data.  PayPal buttons are pretty specific and they essentially give you the complete code.  Only thing unique is Client ID and Plan ID.    Melly, did you ever find out why you got the error or how to fix it?